# MethodHandle with general non-void return filter?

Tags: java, methodhandle

I'm trying to establish a `MethodHandle` that has a general purpose filter for the return values, by using the [`MethodHandles.filterReturnValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html#filterReturnValue-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-) to do the work.

The problem I have is that I don't know (nor care about) the return type, so I was hoping to just wire up a `Object myfilter(Object obj)` as the `MethodHandle` to filter the return objects through.  However, this isn't apparently allowed in the `MethodHandles.filterReturnValue()` call.

Here's what I was hoping would work (but doesn't)...

```java
package invoke;

import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodType;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MethodHandleReturnExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable
    {
        MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
        Testcase test = new Testcase();
        MethodHandle onCount = findMethodByName(lookup, test, "onCount");
        MethodHandle onNada = findMethodByName(lookup, test, "onNada");
        MethodHandle onText = findMethodByName(lookup, test, "onText");

        onNada.invoke("hello");
        onText.invoke("world");
        onCount.invoke();
        onCount.invoke();
        onCount.invoke();
    }

    private static MethodHandle findMethodByName(MethodHandles.Lookup lookup, Object obj, String methodName) throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException
    {
        Method method = Arrays.stream(obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethods())
                .filter(m -> m.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(methodName))
                .findFirst().get();
        MethodHandle handle = lookup.unreflect(method);
        handle = handle.bindTo(obj);

        if (handle.type().returnType() != Void.TYPE)
        {
            MethodHandle returnFilter = lookup.findVirtual(Util.class, "filter", MethodType.methodType(Object.class,Object.class));
            returnFilter = returnFilter.bindTo(new Util());
            handle = MethodHandles.filterReturnValue(handle, returnFilter);
        }
        return handle;
    }

    public static class Testcase
    {
        int count = 0;

        public int onCount()
        {
            int ret = ++count;
            System.out.printf("onCount() : %d%n", ret);
            return ret;
        }

        public void onNada(String msg)
        {
            System.out.printf("onNada(%s)%n", msg);
        }

        public String onText(String msg)
        {
            System.out.printf("onText(%s)%n", msg);
            return "[text:" + msg + "]";
        }
    }

    public static class Util
    {
        public Object filter(Object obj)
        {
            System.out.printf("# filter((%s) %s)%n", obj.getClass().getName(), obj);
            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that `MethodHandles.filterReturnValue()` is inappropriate for this purpose.

I was then hoping that I could perhaps make a `MethodHandle` that called another `MethodHandle`, but that started to get complicated.

eg:

```java
public Object filter(MethodHandle handle, Object ... args)
{
    Object ret = handle.invoke(args);
    System.out.printf("# filter((%s) %s)%n", ret.getClass().getName(), ret);
    return ret;
}
```

I've tried to get my head around [`MethodHandleProxies`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandleProxies.html) or even [`LamdaMetafactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html), but they are tough to understand from the javadoc and meager examples found online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filterReturnValue` will call the `target` handle is if it were using `invokeExact`, so the return type has to match exactly.

So you have to adapt the return types to be `Object`. The easiest way is to use `asType` (this will automatically box the `int` too):

```
if (handle.type().returnType() != Void.TYPE) {
    handle = handle.asType(handle.type().changeReturnType(Object.class)); // <---

    MethodHandle returnFilter = lookup.findVirtual(Util.class, "filter",
            MethodType.methodType(Object.class, Object.class));
    returnFilter = returnFilter.bindTo(new Util());
    handle = MethodHandles.filterReturnValue(handle, returnFilter);
}
```

Comment: Neat!  But wouldn't the resulting MethodHandle now only work with `.invoke()` and no longer work with `.invokeExact()` ?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt, well the return type has changed to object because of the filter, so you have to account for that too, you could use another filter to change it back though.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Btw, if you're still interested in making a MethodHandle that calls another, you should take a look at [`collectArguments`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html#collectArguments-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-int-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-) :) For instance: `MethodHandles.collectArguments(returnFilter, 0, handle);` would be the equivalent of what you're trying to do with `filterReturnValue`.